# Rails 5: if many params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Is this the best way to write an index method that can accommodate multiple param queries?

```
if params.key?(:user_id)
  Post.where(user_id: params[:user_id])
elsif params.key?(:status)
  Post.where(status: params[:status])
elsif params.key?(:user_id) && params.key?(:status)
  Post.where(user_id: params[:user_id], status: params[:status])
else
  Post.all
end
```

My method doesn't seem to catch the params when there are two.

Comment: Hint: Foo Bar question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use [`ActionController::Parameters#slice`](http://where(post_params)):

```
post_parmas = params.slice(:user_id, :status)
post_params.empty? ? Post.all : Post.where(post_params)
```

Your code problem: if you have `:user_id` or `:status` keys, you are skipping all other logic, including both params presence checking. Checking both params (condition #3) should be first.

Comment: Oh my god, _thank you_. The conditional order. Of course.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you

```
if params.key?(:user_id) && params.key?(:status)
  Post.where(user_id: params[:user_id], status: params[:status])
elsif params.key?(:user_id)
  Post.where(user_id: params[:user_id])
elsif params.key?(:status)
  Post.where(status: params[:status])
else
  Post.all
end
```

If you have multiple conditions need to be added in query based on parameters , you can use below approach. Please take care SQL injection.

```
condition = ""
if(params[:user_id].blank? and params[:user_id].blank?)
    Post.all
else
    condition += "user_id=#{params[:user_id]}" if params.key?(:user_id)
    condition += " AND status=#{params[:status]}" if params.key?(:status)
    Post.where("#{condition}")
end
```